# Keyboard shows up when not needed

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ios4

I've just downloaded SDK 4.0 and I wanted to tun my iPhone application developed against SDK 3.1.3. Unfortunately the app behaves in a strange way in the Simulator for iPhone 4.0.

The first thing is that I have a view with a table view with text fields in the cells. When I show the view the keyboard immediately shows up, but I cannot modify any of the text views. When I try to choose any of the text fields the focus does not change and it ends up without any possibility to modify the text fields.

There is a `UITextFieldDelegate`added to each of the text views, but none of its methods is called when the view shows up (together with the keyboard). When I choose one of the text views the

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

is called and I return `YES`.

This is how the view looks like:

[alt text http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/3310/iphonesimulator.png](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/3310/iphonesimulator.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen this behavior but to troubleshoot I suggest disabling the text fields and seeing if the behavior goes away. If it does, add the textfield back in a pattern until you locate the one triggering the keyboard.

You might also look through the nib/s and see if you have a hidden text field somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
I add all the text field in the code.
After disabling all the text fields the keybord still shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working correctly.
Context:
I had two views: in the first I had text view, and in the second view I had a table view with some text fields. 
Problem:
In the first view I had

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

method returning always `NO`for the text view. This is why when I was showing the second view the keyboard for the text view was still shown. 
It worked wery well in SDK 3.1.3, so it must have been changed in SDK 4.0.